# Set TableView and collectionView in ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I am building an iOS app which is having multiple collectionView some are horizontal some are vertical scroll.

I wanted them to scroll vertically together I read a lot of blogs and came to know it can be done using UITableView. I was implementing UITableView and UICollectionView IN ViewController It this throwing an error.

**Error:**

```
Showing Recent Messages
The dealCollectionViewCell outlet from the BusinesViewControllerr to the UICollectionView 
is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content. [12]

Showing Recent Messages
The dealTableViewCel outlet from the BusinesViewControllerr to the UITableViewCell is 
invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content. [12]
```

I am new to swift does anyone can help me in understanding this error and how to fix this.

I have made a sample project where I made tableView and collection view different classes it works fine. I need to merge that into viewController because I am fetching some data using API from the server and need to display in my 4 different collectionView.

Comment: You need to learn using TableView and CollectionView first. As a beginner, don't directly jump to complex layouts. Read some tutorials first and clear the basics.

Comment: Don't use nesting, its easily done with single collectionview

Comment: You can refer this link collectionviewcell within tableviewcell
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59043807/load-multiple-uicollectionview-in-uitableview-in-view-controller-swift

Answer (score 0):

You should connect outlets from UITableView and UICollectionView instead of their cells

Comment: Ok, then how to collect them?

Comment: see this link: https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/uikit/uitableviewcontroller/

Comment: Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x7fff89793008) to 'Uriba.DealTableViewCell' can you please help me what this issue mean

Comment: there is all you need to know to setup a table or collection view, just follow step by step

Comment: Thanks, I had fixed my issue. The blog you had shared is for static view and I am working for a dynamic view

Answer (score 0):

```
Use a function in tableviewcell class and in cellforrow at call that function like:
UItableviewClass:
func BindData(data: [String]){
self.myData = data
self.myCollectionView.reloadData()
}

in ViewController:
  cellForRowAt:
   cell.BindData(data: anydata)
```