# Load multiple UICollectionView in UITableView in view controller Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am building an iOS application where there are 4 different designs of the UICollectionViewn
in UITableView.

UICollectionViewCell Class Name are : DealCollectionViewCell, FilterCollectionViewCell, ComboCollectionViewCell, BusinessCollectionViewCell

UITableViewCell Class Name are : DealTableViewCell, BusinessTableViewCell, FilterTableViewCell, ComboTableViewCell

Below is UIViewController class code (Class Name HomeViewControllerr)

class extend

```
UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource
```

For UITableView

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if  indexPath.row == 0
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DealTableViewCellId") as! DealTableViewCell

        return cell
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 1
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FilterTableViewCellId") as! FilterTableViewCell

        return cell
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 2
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ComboTableViewCellId") as! ComboTableViewCell

        return cell
    }
    else
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BusinessTableViewCellId") as! BusinessTableViewCell

        return cell
    }
}
```

For UICollectionView

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return dealImageArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "DealCollectionViewCellId", for: indexPath) as? DealCollectionViewCell

    return cell!

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let nextViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProductViewControllerId") as! ProductViewController
    self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
    //self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Now I want to add multiple UICollectionViewCell in cellForItemAt function. Like below (This I had done when I was not using UITableView)

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if  (collectionView == dealCollectionView)
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "DealCollectionViewCellId", for: indexPath) as? DealCollectionViewCell

        return cell!
    }
    else if  (collectionView == comboCollectionView)
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ComboColllectionViewCellId", for: indexPath) as? ComboColllectionViewCell

        return cell!
    }
    else
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "BusinessCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? BusinessCollectionViewCell

        return cell!
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem you are facing in above code?

Comment: @Hima I have a load deal array in dealUICollectionView. How can I load filter, combo and business array in there respective UICollectionView

Comment: You can add same condition `if (collectionView == dealCollectionView)` in this method, `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int` and can return your array.count respectively.

Comment: @Hima I had done it was not working

Comment: @Hima I cannot do collectionView == dealCollectionView as collectionView and tableView both I had delacred in one viewController

Comment: All the above code is of UIViewController. I want to ask should I had declared/ extend UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource in each table view cell ?

Comment: I need to see your whole code, can you send me someway? From your description, it is unclear what you are telling..

Comment: Bcz If I had done if  collectionView == DealCollectionViewCell()
        {
            return dealImageArray.count
        }
        else
        {
            return filterInfoArray.count
        } 
it is going in else part always

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203075/discussion-between-hima-and-sofquestion-9).

Answer (score 4):

```
 extension HomeViewController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 4
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DealTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DealTableViewCell
        cell.DealCollectionView.dataSource = self
        cell.DealCollectionView.delegate = self
        cell.DealCollectionView.tag = 10101
        return cell
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BusinessTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! BusinessTableViewCell
        cell.BusinessCollectionView.dataSource = self
        cell.BusinessCollectionView.delegate = self
        cell.BusinessCollectionView.tag = 10102
        return cell
    } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FilterTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! FilterTableViewCell
        cell.FilterCollectionView.dataSource = self
        cell.FilterCollectionView.delegate = self
        cell.FilterCollectionView.tag = 10103
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ComboTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ComboTableViewCell
        cell.ComboCollectionView.dataSource = self
        cell.ComboCollectionView.delegate = self
        cell.ComboCollectionView.tag = 10104
        return cell
    }
}
}
```

Add the collection view to each tableview cell and set delegate in tableview cell

```
extension HomeViewController : UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if collectionView.tag == 10101 {
        return 3
    } else if collectionView.tag == 10102 {
        return 3
    } else if collectionView.tag == 10103 {
        return 3
    } else if collectionView.tag == 10104 {
        return 3
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if collectionView.tag == 10101 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DealCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DealCollectionViewCell

        return cell
    } else if collectionView.tag == 10102 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BusinessCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! BusinessCollectionViewCell

        return cell
    } else if collectionView.tag == 10103 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FilterCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! FilterCollectionViewCell

        return cell
    } else if collectionView.tag == 10104 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ComboCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ComboCollectionViewCell

        return cell
    }

    return UICollectionViewCell()
}
}
```

For reload the collectionView in use

```
if let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)) as? tableViewCell {
cell.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Hi @gowri, I have two collecitonviews, First one is menu list, second one is list of items. I need to update the second collection view from the first collectionview  click(). Can you help me.